# ffmpeg memory leak when use h264_nvenc encode

Tags: memory, ffmpeg, nvidia

when i use valgrind to check ffmpeg memory leak, it reports:

> ==2550== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 478 of 2,201
>
> ==2550==    at 0x4C29F73: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
>
> ==2550==    by 0x57D3236D: ???
>
> ==2550==    by 0x57D316D8: ???
> ==2550==    by 0x57D212E1: ???
> ==2550==    by 0x57D2EB3B: ???
>
> ==2550==    by 0x802E8B8: nvenc_open_session (nvenc.c:237)
>
> ==2550==    by 0x802F2A2: nvenc_check_device (nvenc.c:446)
>
> ==2550==    by 0x802F7D6: nvenc_setup_device (nvenc.c:563)
>
> ==2550==    by 0x8032CDC: ff_nvenc_encode_init (nvenc.c:1499)
>
> ==2550==    by 0x81C5FC6: avcodec_open2 (utils.c:935)

it can be reproduced

ffmpeg version:4.2.1

> command: valgrind --leak-check=yes --log-file=log.txt myprogram

If I use h264 encoder which is by CPU, the other code is the same, there is no memory leak.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: if i use h264 encoder which is by cpu, the other code is the same, there is no memory leak

Comment: Additional info should be added to the your question. Use the EDIT button.

Comment: Thank you, i already know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

i also ask this question on NVIDIA developer forums.The response is as below. Also you can visit the original website:https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/memory-leak-in-nvencopenencodesessionex/254738

This is a known issue which was fixed end of 2021 in drivers starting with the 495 release train.

This is a non-critical issue which creates those 32 bytes once per encoder instance. Which means if you use for example ffmpeg command line tools, it will be cleaned up after the process ends. Only if you create a lot of encoder sessions within one process or start a lot of parallel processes for encoding will this be noticeable since it is only 32 bytes.

So I suggest you update your NVIDIA driver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To be an answer, the information must be in the body of the answer, not a link. Please, PLEASE read the Help section to understand how this site works.